# ffmpeg mp4 video cannot be played in old tv

Tags: video, ffmpeg, windows-10, mp4

I've convert many video to mp4 using ffmpeg and playing well on my TV.
But ever since I change my laptop to a new one, my conversion failed to load on the TV.

I have tried to download old-stable ffmpeg Windows build, I tried also download a win-32 build, no good.
(I'm using x64 laptop with Windows 10 64-bit, just the same like previous laptop)
I also tried to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, still no good.

This is code that I used to convert using ffmpeg:
`ffmpeg -f concat -i "D:\Convert\LISTCAM.TXT" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p "Apr 2nd.mp4"`

I also tried to compare using `ffmpeg -i` between my playable mp4 file with new not-playable mp4,
both are just similar except the encoder header.

Playable mp4:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'E:\2020-DEC\Dec 13-PSTM-001.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 01:01:47.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1586 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x714 [SAR 1071:1072 DAR 120:67], 1450 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Non-playable mp4:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\Convert\TEST.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:18.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4483 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x808, 4517 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : video.264#trackID=1:fps=23.976 - Imported with GPAC 0.5.0-rev
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Update:

- I did a single-file input instead of a concatenation list.
- I did a codec copy from a playable file, it works, but when I try to re-encode, it does not.
  `ffmpeg -i "Playable-video-file.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac "Output.mp4"` this works

`ffmpeg -i "Playable-video-file.mp4" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v main -level:v 3.0 -preset:v medium -c:a aac "Output.mp4"` and this don't

- I did the very same syntax and the same ffmpeg build on a friend's laptop with the same Windows 10 x64 architecture... the output file works fine and playable on my TV...
- Friend's is Intel i5, mine is Intel i7

Comment: The inputs in `D:\Convert\LISTCAM.TXT` possibly do not have matching parameters.

Comment: The list as input is fine, I have done hundreds of conversion using the same method list. I also did a direct file as input, yet the output remain unplayable on some device.

Comment: Strange. Try downloading the most recent build from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Make sure to download the version with the date and not the release version.

Comment: @llogan I did, but seems no luck yet for me. I have tried some other player with USB reader, and it's all fine with my conversion file, but my TV. Well I think it's time to move on.

Answer (score 0):

`-f concat` implies that you are concatenating multiple files, first make sure that they will all individually play before and after being converted and then also try specifying the x264 profile *and* level by adding:

`-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v main -level:v 3.0 -preset:v medium`

CRF and preset are at the default values, if that works but you want more quality/speed just tune those.

I would also use the file that will already play as your test file, rather than the input list, start with a known good and work from there.

The full command line would be:

`ffmpeg -f concat -i "D:\Convert\LISTCAM.TXT" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v main -level:v 3.0 -preset:v medium -c:a aac "Apr 2nd.mp4"`

Comment: Yes, all the files concatenated are playable... even the concatenated output is actually playable on laptop, but not on the TV.  I did your suggestion, but the file is remain not-playable on TV.